# MongoDB sort the query by the first field, then by the second

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I'm trying to sort my query:

```
await Content.find({
    $text: {$search: `\"${query}\"`},
}
```

It querys in the title, text and author of a document. Basically, I want to order it by the fields, so that if the searched word is in the title field it is on the first place and so on with the author and text.

Is this even possible with mongodb or do I have to do this on the Javascript side?

Comment: why the quotes?

Comment: Double checking:   per the docs "$text performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index."   Are your `title`,`text`, and `author` part of the text index?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti yes they are all part of the index

Comment: @skara9 The quotes are there because the text has multiple lines with \n and without the quotes you wouldn't be able to query for the word after the character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most search technologies, have an option called `boost`. If you take solr, elasticsearch there you could apply this option to assign a priority.

It is called weights in mongo.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/)

CreateIndex takes extra object where weight of each field part of text index can be specified. Hence the score of the resulted document multiplied by this weight factor.

Comment: Thank you it works now. But I have one question left. Is it possible to sort them alphabetically without changing the weight?

Comment: You need to set the weight in alphabetical order. All has to be manipulated via weights.

Comment: How can I do this? Like i have seen textScore etc. but I don't know how I would use them to sort alphabetically without changing the weights ranking

Comment: You cannot do that without weights.

Comment: Ah yeah, I tested some things now and I understand how its working. But I guess it isn't such an big problem without alphabetical sorting. Still thank you for your help